# SAS - RENAME of variables in dataset - performance

Tags: sas

I have many variables in the dataaset that has to be rename to another varaible for the down stream processing .This Rename functionality in SAS is taking too much time is there any way i can reduce the time ?

```
 DATA UPDATE2(RENAME=(ClassId=BClassId 
TemplateId=TId ResourceId=RId 
StartTime=STime 
EndTime=ETime Flags=MBUF Amount=Amt) 
index=(Update2_ORDINAL));
MPRINT(PROCESSING_SS):   SET XML.UPDATE2();
MPRINT(PROCESSING_SS):   RUN;

NOTE: There were 846 observations read from the data set XML.UPDATE2.
NOTE: The data set WORK.UPDATE2 has 846 observations and 9 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      **real time           5.89 seconds
      user cpu time       5.10 seconds
      system cpu time     0.27 seconds**
```

IF you see the log it takes too my time just for 846 records

Any thoughts?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does use of a libref value of `XML` mean that the source data is actually an XML file and not a physical SAS dataset? That might explain the speed as 846 observations should not take 6 seconds on any hardware that is not 20+ years old.

Comment: yes , its  from XML Engine , when i try to copy that data set into SAS that takes more than 5 seconds

Comment: So just change the name in the map file that you give to the XML engine that tells it how to name the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename variables in PROC DATASETS, which then only changes the metadata it does not change the main data set so it's much faster.

```
proc datasets lib=XML;
modify update2;
rename  classID = BclassID templateID = TID;
run;quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to copy the data to change a variables name.  If you have an actual SAS dataset you can use PROC DATASETS to rename the variable.

But you could also just leave the name as it is and add a RENAME= dataset option to the step that uses the file.

```
proc freq data=XML.UPDATE2(RENAME=
   (ClassId=BClassId TemplateId=TId ResourceId=RId StartTime=STime EndTime=ETime
    Flags=MBUF Amount=Amt
   ))
;
tables ...
```

But it looks like you are reading data from an XML file instead.  For that you could just modify the map file to name the variable differently.  [User Guide](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=engxml&docsetTarget=titlepage.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

```
libname test xmlv2 'C:\Example\Nhl.xml' xmlmap='C:\Example\Nhl.map';
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. but one question here is when i use XML engine to parse the big XML and try to copy all the dataset from XML engine to SAS using proc copy its taking huge time (for copying 30 dataset it takes 3 minutes) is there any way to reduce it ? and i tried SET statement as well but no luck

Comment: Not sure of any way to make XML faster. You might see if you can get your data delivered in a more user friendly format. You might look at using some external XML aware process to transform the XML into a simple delimited text file(s) for the tables/variables that you want.